# df.iat not fast enough for linear scan over large dataset when grouped

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, data-science, graph-theory

I have a traffic dataset of camera sightings of license plates. It has approx. 100M points that can be thought of as { camera ID, license plate, timestamp } 3-tuples. There are around 2000 unique cameras and a few million unique license plates. The cameras cover most, but not all of the city and most data points (around 70%) have a license plate (as opposed to a blank). I am trying to reconstruct a flow network of common driving routes, and want to this network to be as follows. There should be an edge between two cameras A and B if and only if

1. There are a lot of direct trips from A to B (ie. a lot of cars that are seen at camera A immediately before being seen at camera B)
2. Most of these trips took a reasonable amount of time/didn't take too long (ie. we compute the median time of all trips A->B and then only count a trip as a "direct trip" if it's <150% of the median). This eliminates the possibility that most trips A->B went through other cameras but those just happened not to be in the dataset because they are blanks.

The way I'm doing this is as follows. I first sort by time into car-days (trips) so each group represents one car's movement through cameras on one day, in chronological order. This is done by

`grouped = full_data.sort_values('time_seconds').groupby(['placa_encoded', 'date'])`

Then I create a matrix `count_mat = np.zeros((num_cameras, num_cameras))` where `count_mat[i, j]` represents the number of times camera `i` immediately precedes camera `j` in the data (if the given duration between the sightings isn't 'too long'). This is done as follows.

```
for name, group in grouped: 
    for x in range(len(group)-1):
        c1, c2 = group.iat[x, 0], group.iat[x+1, 0]
        t1, t2 = group.iat[x, 3], group.iat[x+1, 3]
        # from, to camera codes, eg. 480502114, 480221121 
        i, j = code2index(c1), code2index(c2)
        if (abs(t2-t1) < 1.5 * median_mat[i][j]): 
            # this means A->B was a direct trip that someone took in a reasonable time
            count_mat[i][j] += 1
```

Here, `median_mat[i,j]` is the pre-calculated median times over all trips to go from camera `i` to camera `j`. `t1` and `t2` are the timestamps for a data point, and `c1` and `c2` are camera codes.

The problem is that the above code is taking hours to run over all 100M points, even though it is theoretically O(n) if I assume that `iat` is constant time, since it goes through each data point once and all matrix accesses are random access and so constant time. I used to use `iloc` but that was much slower still. Having looked up similar questions on SO, I people say that vectorizing or using list comprehensions in similar situations goes much faster, but I can't see how either of those would apply/be used here, or how I could do this more efficiently. Currently, it takes a couple of hours to go through all the points on my MacBook Pro, but I'm hoping to find a way to have it done in a couple minutes, if not less.

For completeness, `code2index` is an O(1) helper that maps camera IDs into the range [0, num_cameras] so that we know where each camera goes in the various matrices. It is as follows.

```
def code2index(code): 
    # takes camera code like 480502114 and converts to index into count_mat 0 <= i < 1832
    if (code in c2i.keys()): return c2i[code]
    else: 
        n = len(c2i.keys())
        # eg. if there are 2 keys, then we want to put new code into dict[2]
        c2i[code] = n 
        return n
```

Any ideas/optimizations are much appreciated. Any general pointers on how to conceptually think about optimality *a priori* before sitting down and writing this code would also be great. Thank you!

Comment: Step 1: port code to compiled language ( e.g. c++ ).  This will be much faster than python Step 2. Time profile code to see where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Profile point is well taken, but I don't think it's fair to just say it should be done in C++; many people use Python for large dataset manipulation/parsing perfectly fine -- even for larger and more complicated datasets than mine -- so I'm sure there are ways to do it fine within Python/Pandas/NumPy, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, compare time profile of your python implementation of code2index(code) with the C++ implementation

```
int code2index( const std::string& code )
{
  static std::set<std::string> ​mySet;
 ​ return mySet.insert(code).second - mySet.begin();
}
```

I anticipate the C++ code will be at least 50 times faster.

Comment: I appreciate your point, coming from a C++ background myself, but in this case the vast majority of time spent in the loop is on `iat`, a Pandas feature for which there is no easy equivalent in C++, because other operations, including `code2index`, are O(1). I think porting to C++ is premature optimization and am sure there are many ways to make this much faster by just using different Pandas/Python functions in a better way. One could respond 'just port to C++' to any question about Python optimizations in this way, but that would be missing the point. Thanks anyways, though!

Answer (score 0):

I would sort all camera ID's, replace them with numbers between [0, len(camera IDs)]. This sorts the (seemingly) unnecessary code2index function. Also, reduce the lookup by taking two indexes at once. Lastly, remove the if-statement and make it a pure boolean computation.

```
for name, group in grouped: 
    for x in range(len(group)-1):
        c1, c2 = group.iloc[[x, x+1], 0]
        t1, t2 = group.iloc[[x, x+1], 3]

        count_mat[c1][c2] += ( abs(t2-t1) < 1.5 * median_mat[c1][c2] ) * 1
```

Hope this speeds up the work!

Comment: Thanks, but I believe `iat` is more than twice as fast as `iloc` so we'd be slowing things down if we replaced two `iat` with one `iloc`. I agree about pure boolean, but I still think there must be a smarter way than using `iloc` or `iat` and that's by far the performance bottleneck.

Comment: Did you try avoiding the code2index by first replacing your camera ID's with numbers between 1 and 2000, so that you can immediately fill the matrices?

Comment: Another suggestion: I think you could drop the entire inner for-loop by using a group.rolling() function. Take a window of 2, and absorb your count_mat function. See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

Comment: Or, create an index for each contiguous group of points [x, x+1], and do another group by. This groupby returns a few columns, namely c1,c2,t1,t2. Then, you can probably fill the count_mat using vectorized functions.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try those two changes.